# Visual Studio 2022 standalone JavaScript project

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Looking at the available project templates I see "standalone JavaScript React project" and "standalone JavaScript Vue project", however what is the best/correct setup for a vanilla JavaScript project ? (multiple html/js/css files with some third party libs ie bootstrap)

Am I missing a template ? should I just open a blank project and add the files ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an Empty web project (no C#, no MVC, no .Net References) in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164132/how-to-create-an-empty-web-project-no-c-no-mvc-no-net-references-in-visual)

Comment: thanks @Phil the answer there seems quite hackish and may be quite dated as VS22 promises a better JS experience ?

Comment: To be honest, I'd just use Visual Studio Code with the Live Server extension. It's not really clear what you want out of the IDE when working with a simple static web project